# IsDefault for WPF button - overriding everything

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Is there an option to force Enter to be the main key on certain view? What I want to achieve is whenever I click "Enter" key I want to invoke button which has "IsDefault" property set to true, no matter what is focused.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AbinMathew it is not answer for my question. The problem I have is that when I click button1 and then click "Enter" my Default button is not invoked but once again button1 because of focus. I want to override all of them.

Comment: if focus changes then set the focus to default button in button1 click event or command. so your default button will work when hitting on enter.

Comment: I want to have generic idea so I am done with behaviour that catches all enters on the view before getting any control.

Comment: thats what IsDefault does

Comment: Nope, because IsDefault doesn't catch enter if something had catched it before. My solution is to make View-level based tunneling behavior which catches PreKeydown event before any of controls which means that it doesn't matter what is focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to intercept the `RoutedEvent` before it gets to the controls that try to react to it:

Connect to the [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event as far up the visual tree as you want to catch it. React to it there accordingly if the enter key was pressed, e.g. run the same code as in your button, and then set in the eventargs `Handled` to `true`.

```
private void previewKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

The `Preview` events are part of the `RoutedEvent` system in WPF. The 2 mechanisms are called Tunneling and Bubbling. [Here you can read more on that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This is exactly I mentioned in my previous comment, but thanks for answer anyway :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't expand the comments and missed therefore yours - that solution just came to my mind and nobody had posted an answer yet. Glad that you got something workable though :-)